# Why is the GoogLeNet retrained model size less compared to others?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

I have some questions if someone can answer me or guide me articles to understand them. 
I investigated different pre-trained model i.e. AlexNet, VGG, GoogLeNet, InceptionV3 and ResNet.

**(Size are as AlexNet: 207.266MB , VGG: 407.981MB, GoogLeNet:22MB, ResNet: 155MB )**

Q1) Among all the size of the GoogLeNet and InceptionV3 is less among all?
What can be the be the possible reasons? Usage of inception models or usage of 1x1 convolution filter?

Q2) Why the size of AlexNet is more than GoogLeNet and ResNet? Is it because of computation of gradient at each layer?

The other question is related to understanding the training progress provided by MATLAB?  Why the model struggle in the initial epoch? what are the possible options? 
 [image]

I Will be really grateful if you can help me in finding answers to these questions?

Comment: Model size is directly correlated with the number of parameters (weights) in the model, so all can be explained just by this.

Comment: ok. thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you so much for the answer regarding size. What about the graph? Why there are peaks in initial epoch? because of difficulty in convergence to local minima in initial epoch? Or something else? If you can also give me some hints on them it will be your great help